# How to cofigure smart double brackets for links?

Tags: org-mode

I use double brackets heavily for links. Is there anyway to config smart autocompletion such that pressing brackets twice I get [[] instead of [[]], and once the prompt is at left of ] in [[], pressing ] again close the link, that is, produces the final [[]]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first thought is use org: C-c C-l, and type your link, with optional description.

Second thought, write a function like:

```
(defun my-link (s)
 (interactive "sLink: ")
 (insert (format "[[%s]" s)))
```

and bind it to some key if you like.

Third thought: look into yasnippet or skeleton.

Comment: That works. I am currently using a yasnippet to trigger that (simply [[$1][$2]$0, triggered by "link"). It always work. But for some reason that I don't quite understand, the emacs running in ubuntu do what I described in the question, on mac it doesn't.